# nested (double) loop with thymeleaf

Tags: loops, nested, double-quotes, thymeleaf

I've tried searching for existing answers, but I could not find them.

I'd like to access an ArrayList from an object within an ArrayList, so:

Basically two classes: Glossary and Word. 
Glossary contains a list with Word objects, the class Word contains a list with more Word objects (related words)

```
<table>
<span th:each="word : ${glossary.words}">
 <td>
  <tr th:each="relatedWord: ${word.relatedWords}">
    <p th:text="${relatedWord.getName()}"></p>
  </tr>
 <td>
</span>
</table>
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me..

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure but I don't think you can access public non-static getters like you do (assuming `getName()` is marked as public).

You should try:

```
<table>
    <span th:each="word : ${glossary.words}">
        <td>
            <tr th:each="relatedWord: ${word.relatedWords}">
                <p th:text="${relatedWord.name}"></p>
            </tr>
        <td>
    </span>
</table>
```

One note: the above code is absolutely not valid XHTML (`span` directly inside `table`, `tr` directly inside `td`).

Comment: No..yes you are right, about the markup. The actual code is not like that, probably made a mistake when creating this 'more readable', yet identical piece of code.

Comment: You could use <th:block /> instead of <span/>, to make it a valid XHTML

Comment: this comment should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've trying to figure out this too. Using Spring Boot back-end.

I have a class `App` with a `@ManyToOne` relationship with `Cube`.

I'm trying to produce a table where each record represents an `App` and within one of the cells would list out the related `Cube` objects.

```
<tr th:each="app : ${apps}">
  <td th:text="${app.id}">ID</td>
  <td th:text="${app.name}">Name</td>
  <td th:text="${app.description}">Description</td>
  <td th:text="${app.url}">URL</td>
  <td>
    <ul>
      <li th:each="cube : ${app.cubes}">
        <span th:text="${cube.name}">Name</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I currently have 3 `App`s in the database, each with 3-4 related `Cube`s.

The `App` rows are generating correctly, but the I am only getting a single `Cube` item listed. As it happens, the id of both objects is `1` I noticed.